# Grab text id with javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

HTML:

```
  <text id = "addedit">add/edit</text>
  <text id = "addedit2">add/edit</text>
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#addedit").click(function(){
    var html = "stuff";
  });
});
```

I have multiple text IDs, and how do i call each IDs so in the javascript code i don't have to call "#addedit1", "#addedit2", "#addedit3", etc.

Comment: Use class instead of ID

Comment: @FrebinFrancis if you wrote this out into a full answer I'd upvote.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following:

```
$("text[id^='addedit']")
```

This will return all  with ids starting (^=) with addedit.

But its better to use class rather than id.

Comment: Agreed with this answer

Answer (score 2):

It's better to use classes rather than id's for achieving these kind of requirements . Use classes as below.

```
<style>
    .wantedText{

    }
</style>

<text id = "addedit" class = "wantedText">add/edit</text>
<text id = "addedit2" class = "wantedText">add/edit</text>
```

then use that class to refer to the text boxes.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".wantedText").click(function(){
         var html = "stuff";
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can use some thing like following

```
<text id = "addedit" class="addedit">add/edit</text>
<text id = "addedit2" class="addedit">add/edit</text>
```

And Write script like following :

```
  $(".addedit").click(function(){
    alert(this.id);
  var html = "stuff"; });
```

Here You are Getting the id of the text. so you can do anything with that id.
Hope it helps.

Thank you.

Comment: isn't this a duplicate of the other existing answer?

Comment: I have made this in my fiddel and then posted.